# C# Get entry in float[,] that's part of List<float[,]>

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a List of two-dimensional float arrays:

```
List<float[,]> nodes = new List<float[,]>();
```

I do some things and finally get an zerobased index of the float[,] which I want to use (e.g. 2 for the third array)

Now I want to get a value out of this array. I thought it might work like

```
float foo = nodes[selectedIndex][0,0]
```

to get me the element [0,0] in the array at nodes[selectedIndex]. What shall I say? Doesn't work. Just works over

```
float[,] tmp = nodes[selectedIndex];
float foo = tmp[0,0];
```

So as far as I understand I need to allocate memory twice for the array (once in the List, once in tmp) just to get ONE value. That can't be it, I hope?! Isn't there a shortcut to get to this value?

Hope you can help me!

Comment: "Doesent work" - does it give you an error?

Comment: try this: `((float[,])nodes[selectedIndex])[0,0]`

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't an appropriate error description. What exactly is happening? Are you getting a compiler error? A runtime exception? This code generally works. It must be a problem in your specific code. Maybe you didn't add anything into `nodes`?

Comment: @JesseJames: The indexer of `List<T>` is strong typed. Your cast is redundant.

Comment: Your code is valid and should work. Also note that in C# arrays are reference types therefore you're not alllocating new memory by moving into a local first

Comment: There's no syntactic error in your code. What is variable `selectedIndex`? Is it `Int32`? Are there any elements in `nodes`? Is there element [0,0] in your array? And finally, have you tried to debug your code?

Answer (score 1):

```
float foo = nodes[selectedIndex][0,0]
```

Will work perfectly fine as is, its just intellisense that can't pick up on it.

Also when assigning the value to `tmp` you are not allocating any significant amount of memory, the tmp variable just points to the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

This works :

```
float foo = (nodes[selectedIndex])[0,0];
```

But also works:

```
            List<float[,]> nodes = new List<float[,]>();
            float[,] fl = new float[2, 2];
            fl[0, 0] = 2.2f;
            nodes.Add(fl);
            float foo = nodes[0][0, 0];
```

Maybe you didn't instantiated float array?

Answer (score 0):

This code is valid and works. The problem must be something else. Maybe there is no entry in `nodes` with an index of `selectedIndex`?

---

A small sample to demonstrate that the syntax is correct:

```
List<float[,]> nodes = new List<float[,]>();
nodes.Add(new float[2,2]{{1,2},{3,4}});
float foo = nodes[0][0,0];
```

See it live: http://ideone.com/R2Drh